# Alternative function for LAG in SQL

Tags: sql-server, row-number, partition-by

I know this question has been asked a million times and I know what functions to use but I don't know how to put it together. I am new to `SQL`, been working on it for 2 months with no formal training. I have a table (see below), I need to group it by `acountid` and populate the `TaxDiff` column by subtracting the previous year's `normalTax` amount from the subsequent year. I figured it out using the `LAG` function but soon discovered that I was using an old version of SQL. I know I need to use the `Row Partition` function but I am not sure how to put it together. Do any of you perhaps know how to go about doing this? I am using **SQL server 2008** (cannot upgrade as this decision is not up to me) and my table is much bigger than this, a few thousand lines.

| AccountId | Year | NormalTax | Date | SeqNo | TaxDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9000156 | 2019 | 15293056 | 2019-10-25 | 3 | NULL |
| 9000156 | 2018 | 118592 | 2018-11-30 | 1 | NULL |
| 9000611 | 2015 | 1000000 | 2015-10-30 | 1 | NULL |
| 9000611 | 2014 | 750000 | 2014-12-31 | 4 | NULL |
| 9000611 | 2013 | 659923 | 2014-01-30 | 2 | NULL |
| 9001230 | 2020 | 50000000 | 2020-06-25 | 1 | NULL |
| 9001230 | 2019 | 1500000 | 2019-12-31 | 1 | NULL |
| 9001230 | 2018 | 1750000 | 2018-09-25 | 3 | NULL |
| 9001230 | 2017 | 15000000 | 2017-06-30 | 2 | NULL |
| 9001230 | 2016 | 12500000 | 2017-02-20 | 2 | NULL |

Comment: What *is* your version of SQL Server? (`SELECT @@VERSION`.) It's good to know exactly what is and isn't available.

Comment: If you can't use `LAG` this means you're using an end of life version of SQL Server; this is a far larger problem. You need to get that upgrade path complete ASAP. SQL Server 2008 (the most recent version to go End of Life) has been end of life of 18 months; more than enough time to have completed any upgrades by now.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008. I cannot do an upgrade because this is the version my employer is using.  :(

Comment: To add, my table is much bigger than this, a few thousand lines......

Comment: @Larnu Please, do not always suggest using newer versions - most developers have no say about (local or customer) infrastructure, they are tasked to work on existing software. For example our customers have variety of SQL servers (from 2005 to 2019) - we cannot force them upgrade, because this is just too expensive for them.

Comment: @Arvo upgrading is vitally important. If you don't believe that, you are mistaken. Expense isn't really an "excuse" in my opinion as Express is free, and Microsoft is very open about it's end of life dates; you literally have years to budget for it. The fact is that using end of life software, that isn't supported (which it can be but is expensive too) is a huge security flaw and **needs** to be addressed. That isn't something that's up for debate; it's a fact. A company not addressing their end of life software is just negligence.

Comment: Also, if it concerning how many users still don't know that the version they are using is End of life. I'm pretty confident there was a SQL Server 2005 user I saw last year that had no idea that they hadn't had any security updates for 4 years because it was EoL; and thus weren't safe from Spectre and Meltdown.

Comment: @Larnu Apparently we live on quite different worlds (I have yet to see any security problem in our customers local SQL installations, but I hear about expenses every other day). I do not argue about upgrading importance - I just suggest to not talk about upgrades, when someone is asking, how to solve some specific problem on some specific (old) software version :)

Comment: Apparently we do, @Arvo , as GDPR requires that we keep up to date and secure with our data. Hopefully, therefore, the OP isn't dealing with any EU or UK clients (although no longer part of the EU, the UK still adhere to and are covered by GDPR at this time). :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please start with something like that:

```
WITH  CTE(AccountId,CalendarYear,NormalTax,Date,SeqNo,TaxDiff) AS
 (

     select 9000156,    2019,   15293056,   '2019-10-25',   3,  NULL
          UNION ALL
      SELECT 9000156 ,  2018,   118592,     '2018-11-30' ,  1,  NULL
          UNION ALL
      SELECT 9000611 ,  2015 ,  1000000,    '2015-10-30',   1 , NULL
          UNION ALL
      SELECT 9000611 ,  2014,   750000 ,    '2014-12-31',   4,  NULL
          UNION ALL
     SELECT 9000611 ,   2013 ,  659923,     '2014-01-30',   2 , NULL
          UNION ALL
     SELECT 9001230 ,   2020 ,  50000000 ,  '2020-06-25',   1,  NULL
          UNION ALL
     SELECT 9001230 ,   2019 ,  1500000 ,   '2019-12-31',   1,  NULL
           UNION ALL
     SELECT 9001230 ,   2018 ,  1750000,    '2018-09-25',   3,  NULL
           UNION ALL
     SELECT 9001230 ,   2017 ,  15000000,   '2017-06-30' ,  2 , NULL
           UNION ALL
     SELECT 9001230,    2016,   12500000,   '2017-02-20',   2,  NULL
 )
 SELECT C.*,X.PREV_TAX,C.NormalTax-X.PREV_TAX AS DIFF
   FROM CTE AS C
   OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT NORMALTAX AS PREV_TAX FROM CTE AS C2 WHERE C.AccountId=C2.AccountId
          AND C.CalendarYear=C2.CalendarYear+1
    )X
 ORDER BY C.AccountId,C.CalendarYear
```

Comment: This would be labour intensive I'm afraid, my table has a few thousand lines. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Sure. Just replace FROM CTE AS C with FROM YourTable AS C.

Comment: When I do this should I exclude all the parts with the UNION ALL function?

Comment: Yes. Please try to execute only the query        SELECT C.*,X.PREV_TAX,C.NormalTax-X.PREV_TAX AS DIFF
   FROM YourTable AS C
   OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT NORMALTAX AS PREV_TAX FROM YourTable AS C2 WHERE C.AccountId=C2.AccountId
          AND C.CalendarYear=C2.CalendarYear+1
    )X
 ORDER BY C.AccountId,C.CalendarYear

Comment: Sergey, you are a genius! Thank you so much for your help with this! Appreciate it!

Comment: Always welcome, but please check the result twice :-). Hope, it is OK

Comment: I am busy checking the results now and so far so good, thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated sub query to figure this out. So assuming year is a synonym for tax year

```
drop table t
go
create  table t
(AccountId  int, Year int,  NormalTax int,  Date date,  SeqNo int,  TaxDiff int)
go
insert into t values
(9000156    ,2019   ,15293056   ,'2019-10-25'   ,3  ,null),
(9000156    ,2018   ,118592     ,'2018-11-30'   ,1  ,null),
(9000611    ,2015   ,1000000    ,'2015-10-30'   ,1  ,null),
(9000611    ,2014   ,750000     ,'2014-12-31'   ,4  ,null),
(9000611    ,2013   ,659923     ,'2014-01-30'   ,2  ,null),
(9001230    ,2020   ,50000000   ,'2020-06-25'   ,1  ,null),
(9001230    ,2019   ,1500000    ,'2019-12-31'   ,1  ,null),
(9001230    ,2018   ,1750000    ,'2018-09-25'   ,3  ,null),
(9001230    ,2017   ,15000000   ,'2017-06-30'   ,2  ,null),
(9001230    ,2016   ,12500000   ,'2017-02-20'   ,2  ,null)

select  AccountId   , Year, NormalTax,  Date,   SeqNo,
        (select top 1 normaltax 
        from t t1 
        where t1.accountid = t.accountid and t1.year < t.year order by t1.year desc) lastyear ,
        coalesce(
        t.normaltax - 
        (select top 1 normaltax 
        from t t1 
        where t1.accountid = t.accountid and t1.year < t.year order by t1.year desc),
        normaltax) taxdiff   
from t
order by t.accountid,t.year

AccountId   Year        NormalTax   Date       SeqNo       lastyear    taxdiff
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
9000156     2018        118592      2018-11-30 1           NULL        118592
9000156     2019        15293056    2019-10-25 3           118592      15174464
9000611     2013        659923      2014-01-30 2           NULL        659923
9000611     2014        750000      2014-12-31 4           659923      90077
9000611     2015        1000000     2015-10-30 1           750000      250000
9001230     2016        12500000    2017-02-20 2           NULL        12500000
9001230     2017        15000000    2017-06-30 2           12500000    2500000
9001230     2018        1750000     2018-09-25 3           15000000    -13250000
9001230     2019        1500000     2019-12-31 1           1750000     -250000
9001230     2020        50000000    2020-06-25 1           1500000     48500000

(10 row(s) affected)
```

NOTE I cannot remember when coalesce came in for the handling of nulls You may need to change a bit. You can also test this in a fiddle of your choice..

Comment: I'm fairly sure `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` are pre-SQL Server 2000, if that's the concern. (They are certainly supported in SQL Server 2000 and onwards.)